# Why does Firebase Auth UI always direct to the account creation page despite an account with the email existing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebaseui

I have implemented the Firebase Auth UI for my web application. The initial process of creating an account works fine and is logged to the record but when I attempt to then use that email address to login I am again prompted to create an account? I am learning and new to firebase so I'm just getting to grips with things. Maybe I am implementing this incorrectly?

index.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import firebaseConfig from './firebase-config.js'

// Initialize Firebase
const appInstance = firebaseConfig.appInstance;
const auth = getAuth(appInstance);

// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    signInOptions: [
      {
        provider: EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        requireDisplayName: false
      }
    ],
    signInSuccessUrl: '/editor.html',
});
```

I have tried using incognito mode to ensure fresh browser test sessions along with creating new emails each time to test with. I made sure these accounts were created within the Firebase console. Rebuilding/restarting has not improved this behavior.

Comment: If I do try to create the account again I get this message `"This email already exists without any means of sign-in. Please reset the password to recover.  Dismiss"`

Comment: Could you be hitting this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/1041? That seems to have started on projects created on September 15 or later, as [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is enabled by default since then.